# Codeigniter hook only on updates and inserts

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, date-format

I need to change the format of dates from how it appears to the user ("dd-mm-yyyy") to the mysql format ("yyyy-mm-dd") when updating or inserting them to the database (php - codeigniter is being used). 
There's already a lot of place needing this fix so I thought may be I could do it with the hooks and changing every "2digit-2digit-4digit" to the reversed format.

So is there a way to create a hook that can work only on update and insert data (not to scan every single bit) and is there any other way of doing it without having to place a reverse function call everywhere I have dates inserted - updated?

Comment: No you can't do it with a hook since it's not really to do with a controller. You could create a Helper and put in some convert_date() function and then just run it as needed.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for the answer. So that means you can't do anything directly to the models using hooks huh? Sux! = )

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to use hook here, hook is needed when you need to overide the Core behaviour. Also you doesn't need to worry about your mysql datatypes. What you need is just load date helper and perform mdate() before display the date in your view, something like...

```
$this->load->helper('date');
// assume you hold date (retrieved from your database) in $date variable
$date = mdate('%d-%m-%Y', $date);
```

Comment: Thnx for that. But the problem is only on the inserting - updating part. On the view side things are already just fine (formatting is done). I just wondered if there could be a way of doing it without using the helpers so that I don't have to add one line everwhere with a date insertion - update. To be able to do it like standalone, well you know what I mean.